# What is the best way to do metadata join in Flink datastream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a kafka stream of events that we want to enrich using some metadata that resides inside MySQL DB.

The metadata changes every few hours. Essentially we want to periodically read the DB and keep enriching the events with this new metadata.

One way could be to use Broadcast state with a periodic Source that reads DB every few minutes/hours. Broadcast this stream and use it to join. But the problem could be that the first read of the broadcast stream can be later than some of the messages being read from Kafka Stream.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flink SQL for this. Depending on the exact requirements, you might either do [time-versioned joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/versioned_tables.html) against a CDC stream from the MySQL DB, or do [lookup joins](https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-cookbook/blob/master/joins/04/04_lookup_joins.md) against MySQL (perhaps with the [optional cache](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/jdbc.html#lookup-cache) enabled).

See also https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors.

Update:

If you want to use the DataStream API, but are concerned that some of the kafka messages might be processed before the corresponding data from the broadcast stream is available, you can:

- in the `open()` method of your enrichment function, do an initial query against MySQL to preload the metadata
- if the broadcast data is still unavailable when it's time to do the join, use the data fetched during the `open()`, or use some default value hardwired into the code

Alternatively, you could use the state processor API to bootstrap values for the broadcast state.

Comment: Hey @David Thanks again, Given this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748158/how-could-flink-broadcast-state-be-initialized
A capability like this would have been great.
I was trying to go through the code and seems like StateDescriptor accepts a default value just that the MapDescriptor doesn't exposes it. Will it be okay if we override the class and expose the default value for now?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: David https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/state/StateDescriptor.html#StateDescriptor-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-T- As can be seen StateDiscriptor can accept default value for the state can be set. So in my question if I am able to set default value for the broadcastState I should be able to make the Broadcast state solution work as well correct?

Comment: Providing a default value with the state descriptor isn't doing anything you can't do otherwise. When you need the value of the broadcast state, you can check if it's null and use some other value instead. See my expanded answer above.